# Get data from SOAP call

Tags: php, soap

I have recieved a API from a wsdl webservice that I try to make a call against. I only get return NULL in the arrays when entering the info. Here's what the wsdl looks like:

```
<xs:element name="Amount">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="securityToken" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="testNo" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="testCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

And heres my PHP Soap code:

```
 <?php
    //Create the client object
    $soapclient = new SoapClient('https://example.com/Web.svc?singleWsdl');

    //Use the functions of the client, the params of the function are in 
    //the associative array
    $testNo = 'ABC123';

    $params = array('testNo' => $testNo);
    $response = $soapclient->GetPackagePrice($params);

    var_dump($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SOAP function didn´t accept any classes. Send only the array with content

```
<?php
/* Initialize webservice with your WSDL */
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/PublicWeb.svc?singleWsdl");

/* Set your parameters for the request */
$params = array(
    "securityToken" => "aString",
    "testNo" => "aString",
    "testCode" => "aString"
);

/* Invoke webservice method with your parameters, in this case: GetPackageAmount */
$response = $client->GetPackageAmount($params);

/* Print webservice response */
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: Tried it but it still returns NULL as value data from the array. Updated the php code if you would like to take a look

Comment: Have you any docs about this SOAP endpoint? Or is is private?
And when you don´t need any elements(securityToken,  testCode) then remove it from the array.

Comment: Sorry, it's private. But basically Im supposed send a number as value data to the GetPackageAmount function to recieve data

Comment: When you get `null` as result, then the endpoint don´t understand the request. That mean, your request is invalid.
Can you print the output from `print_r($client->__getFunctions());`and `print_r($client->__getTypes());` ?